# Convert interval to minutes

Tags: oracle

Let's suppose I have 2 intervals:

```
INTERVAL '0 00:30:00' DAY TO SECOND
INTERVAL '0 04:00:00' DAY TO SECOND
```

What is the most elegant way to get amount of minutes in each interval. `30` and `240` accordingly.

Yes, I know I can perform `EXTRACT(HOUR FROM interval) * 60 + EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM interval)`, but this looks terrible to me.

Any better solutions?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

What looks terrible to you, looks perfectly acceptable to me. If you look at the documentation at the arithmetic you can perform on INTERVALs:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements001.htm#sthref175

then you see you can multiply them with numerics. So if you multiply your intervals to 24 and 60, you can get the number of minutes by extracting the number of days. It's more compact, but I doubt if it's more elegant in your view.

```
SQL> create table t (my_interval interval day to second)
  2  /

Table created.

SQL> insert into t
  2  select numtodsinterval(30,'minute') from dual union all
  3  select numtodsinterval(4,'hour') from dual
  4  /

2 rows created.

SQL> select my_interval
  2       , 60 * extract(hour from my_interval)
  3         + extract(minute from my_interval) minutes_terrible_way
  4       , extract(day from 24*60*my_interval) minutes_other_way
  5    from t
  6  /

MY_INTERVAL                    MINUTES_TERRIBLE_WAY MINUTES_OTHER_WAY
------------------------------ -------------------- -----------------
+00 00:30:00.000000                              30                30
+00 04:00:00.000000                             240               240

2 rows selected.
```

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: hehe, great trick ;-) well, I decided to follow my "terrible" way, which is not terrible on second look. thanks.

Comment: the nice thing about "extract(day from 24*60*my_interval)"  is that is will also include any full days as well.

Comment: This helped me! The following doc also helped me:
https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-dates-timestamps-and-intervals#interval

Answer (score 2):

```
(extract(day from my_interval) * 24 * 60 + extract(hour from my_interval)) * 60 + extract(minute from my_interval) my_way
```

Don't forget about days.

Comment: It's identical to the other answer isn't it?

Comment: E.g. "minutes_terrible_way" in answer above lacks days.

Comment: So, minutes_other_way looks fine if you prefer laconical look

Answer (score 0):

Reusing Rob's example above,

```sql
select (sysdate-(sysdate-to_dsinterval(my_interval)))*24*60 from t;
```