# Oracle - derive minutes from a Timestamp value

Tags: oracle, plsql, date-arithmetic

I have a table with a Timestamp(6) column called START_DATE.  Given this query:

SELECT SYSDATE -  MIN(START_DATE) FROM MYTABLE

might return:

0 1:12:32.2819281

I want that returned value in minutes, rounded to nearest minute, no decimal place, e.g.:

73

I know how to do this with queries that don't aggregate, by CAST'ing the START_DATE to a DATE, and then using ROUND, but as soon as I put in the MIN aggregation, that method doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: I asked the similar question not long ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063214/convert-interval-to-minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the stored procedure on this page: [Oracle Timestamp Math](http://mikerault.blogspot.com/2006/07/oracle-timestamp-math.html)

Comment: Thanks but man that really doesn't pass my test for clarity and brevity.  This means that now I have to push code into Oracle, duplicate it across several databases, remember that it's there, tell other people it's there, document it somehow ... Isn't there some way to subtract two timestamps to get seconds between them in a case like this?  Or cast the MIN(START_DATE) to DATE and then do it?

Comment: Casting the timestamp as a date may make it simpler; DATE - DATE is days and fractions thereof, which is pretty easy to cast as minutes.  `TRUNC((SYSDATE - DATE_EXPRESSION) * 24 * 60)`.  After all, it's not like you care about the subsecond precision of the timestamp at that point.