# How do I convert between org.hibernate.type.TimestampType and Oracle SYSDATE?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I have a column that is mapped in hibernate using `org.hibernate.type.TimestampType`. How can I use native Oracle SQL to store and retrieve these values based on an Oracle `TIMESTAMP`?

The column is mapped as `NUMBER(10)`. I tried using some formulas I found for Unix timestamps, but they did not seem to produce the correct results.

Here is a recent timestamp:
`1579730473525`
This would have been some date within the last 2-3 weeks (Jan 2020).

**Details**

I want to use Hibernate Envers, with the `ValidityAuditStrategy`. I'm running into trouble because I'm applying Envers to a database of existing records that have no audit history. What I'm trying to do is do a one-time insert of audit data, using Oracle `SYSDATE` as the timestamp.

Comment: Why is the column number(10) instead of an actual timestamp type?

Comment: @OldProgrammer: I don't know the answer to that. This part of the schema was generated by Hibernate Envers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't sure what format your number 1579730473525 was in, so I took a guess and took the first 10 digits using a `SUBSTR`, and the result was a reasonable 2020 date as follows.

```
SELECT TO_DATE('1970-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') +
NUMTODSINTERVAL(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR('1579730473525',1,10)), 'SECOND') FROM dual;
```

returns

```
22/01/2020 22:01:13
```

Then to get the `TIMESTAMP`, I added the last 4 digits.

```
SELECT to_char(TO_DATE('1970-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') +
NUMTODSINTERVAL(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR('1579730473525',1,10)), 'SECOND') ,'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss') ||'.'||SUBSTR('1579730473525',10,4)
FROM dual;
```

and this returns:

```
2020-01-22 10:01:13.3525
```

(I couldn't find a way of directly converting the 14 digit number back to a YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss:ff format; it complained of precision)

Then to get the number into `TIMESTAMP` format:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('1970-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') +
NUMTODSINTERVAL(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR('1579730473525',1,10)), 'SECOND') ,'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mi:ss') ||'.'||SUBSTR('1579730473525',10,4),'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mi:ss:ff')
FROM dual;
```

and this returns it in the Oracle `TIMESTAMP` as requested, using Oracle SQL.

Just a hint: if you leave out formatting, make a note of your NLS parameter NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT in case you get formatting issues.

Comment: It's probably easier than that: `to_timestamp_tz('01-JAN-1970 00:00:00 +0:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM') + numtodsinterval(1579730473525/1000,'SECOND')`

Comment: Thanks! I'm verifying this now

Comment: Perfect! And it looks like I can convert timestamps back into numbers using this ugly method: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063214/convert-interval-to-minutes
Thanks very much, both of you.